# How can I set a specific product image as alternate/hover image in shopify?

Tags: image, collections, hover, shopify, liquid

The hover function is working well but I want to set an image with a specific ALT tag to be the hover image

This didn't work

```
{% for image in product.media %}
{%if image.alt == variant.featured_media.alt %}
{% capture hover_img %}
<img src="{{ image }}">
{% endcapture %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor % }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

This is the code related to the hover function:

```
 {% if double_img %}
        <div class="collection__image__bottom lazyload lazypreload" data-bgset="{% render 'bgset', image: hover_img %}" role="img" aria-label="{{ product.media[1].alt }}"></div>
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: can you describe what you mean by hover image? Show us some code related to the hover functionality. Right now the snipped you are showing us only assigns a value to the `hover_img` variable. Also the if operation compares the current image alt text to the string "variant.featured_media.alt", I suspect you actually need it to compare to that variable's value, something like this `{% if image.alt == variant.featured_media.alt %}`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, sorry, that was my own code, I have fixed it to compare it to the variable's value by removing the quote marks. The code is too simplistic, but is a gist of what I'm wanting to do. I have also added some code related to the hover function.

Comment: so what is not working more precisely? does `double_img` have the wrong value? Also I'm still not sure how you use `double_img` to be visible on hover, you still need some CSS or JS to use that variable's value.

Comment: At the moment, it is blank / white and there is no double_img showing. However if I replace the hover_img in data-bgset="{% render 'bgset', image: hover_img %}" with product.featured_media[1] then it works but it shows the second product featured image